# How to have a web application support local storage in IE11?

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

We have an application made using HTML5 and jQuery that we got from a partner. Chrome is not allowed in our organisation. When I try to open the application in IE 11, it opens but it also shows an alert

> This browser does not support local storage.

Because of that, the application doesn't work.

When we asked the partner how it is supposed to run, he said:

> The way the version of Internet Explorer you’re running implements
>   local storage requires that the address the file is opened from be an
>   actual domain location and not a mapped address.

Not quite sure what that means. I unzipped those application files on to a folder on the network and tried to run it there. No luck. Same error message.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Well, since IE support localStorage from version 8, someone made a mistake since that error message is custom made, so tell partner that and if they can't fix it, change partner

Comment: https://www.caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Just run into this problem. I tested with IE11 also Edge on Win 10, still localStorage is not supported if the page is opened locally or from a shared folder.

I follow your partner’s explanation and publish the page to a ‘real’ web site- the default web site on localhost, actually- and everything works! So you partner is right.

You need to deploy the web application.